# Determine touch side in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a `touch system` like Instagram in `react-native`. How can I determine if the user has touched on the `right or left side` of the screen? Is it possible to use `swipe` without extraneous libraries?

Comment: Hi! Did my answer helped you? If so, leave an upvote or mark as accepted answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the touch coordinates like this:

`<View onTouchStart={(e) => {console.log('touchMove',e.nativeEvent)}} />`

So you can define on a function it's limits.

Or, you can do it the "Bad way", That would be using 2 transparent touchable views (touchable-opacity, pressable, touchablehighlight) side by side, each one taking half of the screen.

like this (I didn't tested it):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', position: 'absolute', flex: 1}}>
  <touchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => console.log('left side clicked')}>
  </touchableOpacity>

  <touchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => console.log('right side clicked')}>
  </touchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: Bad path doesn't fit because user can click on page content

Comment: I would only work if the "page content" was above the view. But i dont have any idea of how it would be made.

So i think the first path works better.

You only need some testing to see it's limits (like, the %'s)
and then define what is a left side click and a right side click.